# Bind data based on the drop down selection from JSON input in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, angularjs

I hope you guys are doing good in this pandemic time and spare some time to help me out.

I am trying to filter the data based on the drop-down selections of a drop-down list. Here I will get the data from the JSON input.

Here in the Filing Date, I have selected 06/30/2022 so for this date the below region offices are available.

[image]

So if I change the date to any another date like 07/30/2022 it is showing only 2 region offices
[image]

And if we expand the + icon it should display the values like below. That is the requirement and I am done with writing the code for expanding collapse functionality.
[image]

However, I am not sure how I need to bind the data associated with the date and display below. Here is the code I have written

```
var app = angular.module('acturial', ['ui.bootstrap']);

////configure routes
//// TODO:Will implement and configure routes but for now it is not needed
//app.config(function ($routeprovider) {
//    $routeprovider

//        // route for default page
//        // in our case only page exists for now
//        .when('/', { templateurl: 'Index.html', controller: 'Regioncontroller' })

//    //todo: can able to add more pages using by specifying the condition in when clause
//});

var RegionController = function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.title = "Acturial App";
    //$scope.data = [{
    //    "name": "Billings",
    //    "values": ['300031', '300051', '300091', '300111', '300131']
    //}];


    var regionDetails = [
        {
            "date": "6/30/2022",
            "regionOffice": [
                {
                    "name": "Valdosta",
                    "values": [
                        "300031",
                        "300051",
                        "300091",
                        "300111",
                        "300131"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Jackson",
                    "values": [
                        "300031",
                        "300051",
                        "300091",
                        "300111",
                        "300131"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Springfield",
                    "values": [
                        "300031",
                        "300051",
                        "300091",
                        "300111",
                        "300131"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Billings",
                    "values": [
                        "300031",
                        "300051",
                        "300091",
                        "300111",
                        "300131"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "date": "7/30/2023",
            "regionOffice": [

                {
                    "name": "Springfield",
                    "values": [
                        "300031",
                        "300051",
                        "300091",
                        "300111",
                        "300131"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Billings",
                    "values": [
                        "300031",
                        "300051",
                        "300091",
                        "300111",
                        "300131"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ];

    $scope.dataArray = regionDetails;
    //var billingDetails = {
    //    name: 'Billings',
    //    values: ['300031', '300051', '300091', '300111', '300131']
    //}

    //$scope.data = billingDetails;

    // TODO:Still have to make some improvements for the below functions
    // The below code will be used when we have WebAPI endpoint so we can use that to populate the data
    // instead of the static/hard-coded data
    //var onUserComplete = function (response) {
    //    $scope.data = response.data;
    //    $http.get($scope.regionUrl)
    //        .then(onRepos, onError);
    //}

    //onRepos = function (response) {
    //    $scope.data = response.data;
    //};

    //var onError = function (response) {
    //    $scope.error = "Couldn't able to retreive the data";
    //}

    $scope.expandedRegion = null;

    $scope.manageCollapseExpand = function (obj, isExpandedRegion) {
        obj.expanded = !obj.expanded;

        if (obj.expanded) {
            if (!isExpandedRegion) {
                $scope.expandedRegion = obj;
            }
        }
    }
};

app.controller("RegionController", ["$scope", "$uibModal", "$http", RegionController]);
```

Here is the HTML Page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="acturial" ng-controller="RegionController">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="acturial.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.4" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link data-require="font-awesome@*" data-semver="4.5.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="">
        <label>
            Filing Date:
        </label>
         <select ng-model="data.date" ng-options="data.date for data in dataArray" >
        <option value=""> </option>
    </select>
        <br />
    </div>
    <div class="">
        <button class="btn" ng-click="manageCollapseExpand(region, false)">
            <span ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-minus': region.expanded, 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus': !region.expanded }"></span>
        </button>
        {{region.name}} ({{region.values.length}})
    </div>
    <div class="" ng-show="region.expanded">
        <div class="" ng-repeat="value in region.values">
            <div class="">
                {{value}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So can you please help me with binding the data associated with the drop-down selected value and display below?

And below is the structured array I am seeing in the Console

[image]

Comment: What isn't working/? It appears wired correctly. What isn't happening that you want to be happening?

Comment: @Kinglish I am getting the date field but I am not sure how to bind and display the data based on the dropdown selected list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll set up the data like this because ng-options (and choosing a default pre-selected option) requires binding to the same object. On the same object, we'll bind the chosen date, and the full array. Plus we need a variable for the index, which will be used to associate the office list with a particular date.

```
$scope.selectedDateIndex= null
$scope.ds = {};
$scope.ds.dataArray = regionDetails;
$scope.ds.date = $scope.ds.dataArray[0].date // this is our default  pre-selected date
$scope.onSelectDate() // this will trigger showing the default date's office list

// this function will take the date that is chosen, find the data set in the array that matches, and set the `$scope.selectedDateIndex` we'll need
    $scope.onSelectDate =  function () {
      let date = $scope.ds.date;
       console.log(date)
        $scope.ds.dataArray.forEach((el, index) => {
            if (el.date == date) $scope.selectedDateIndex = index
        })
    }
```

For the `<select>`, set up an `ng-change` method. Also, notice the ng-model points at the object we set up before, and `ng-options` has this format `optionValue as optionName forEach item in dataArray`. For this to work, angular has to associate both option name and value.

```
<select ng-model="ds.date" 
    ng-options="data.date as data.date for data in ds.dataArray" 
    ng-change="onSelectDate()">
</select>
```

Then, here you had 2 outer divs, both using the `region` object which was wrong. I combined them. Your toggle button shouldn't call an outside function - just set region.expanded = !region.expanded. That way we keep it inside the object `region` which only exists in this loop.

```
<div class="" 
    ng-if="selectedDateIndex !== null" 
    ng-repeat="region in ds.dataArray[selectedDateIndex].regionOffice">
    <!-- for the rest of this loop we can work with the `region` object -->
    
    <button class="btn" ng-click="region.expanded = !region.expanded">
        <span 
            ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-minus': region.expanded, 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus': !region.expanded }"></span>
    </button>
    {{region.name}} ({{region.values.length}})
    <div class="" ng-show="region.expanded">
        <div class="" 
            ng-repeat="value in region.values">
            <div class="">
                {{value}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can't test this, so if you run into an error, let me know.

Comment: That was not part of your initial code or requirement. You asked how to bind the date from the pulldown to the display, and hopefully this code does that. I showed how to affect the display based on the date selected, and how to display the values based on the region selected.

Comment: Thanks for showing me that, I am okay without a table but the code you gave is not displaying anything in the HTML. I just need to bind the data based on dropdown selection and display the data associated with the input given. I will update it later for now I just need to display data. Thanks for guiding me though

Comment: Ok, i can help step you through it. Are you seeing the select menu options? When you select one, do you get an error in the javascript?

Comment: I couldn't able to see anything on the HTML page. I did the Inspect but I believe it is not rendering to the HTML. I am seeing the below in the HTML body

<!-- ngRepeat: region in dataArray[selectedDateIndex].regionOffice -->

Comment: so there's nthing on the page? No <select> menu?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I am not seeing anything on the page.

Comment: I thought you had parts of this working when you posted your question, is that not the case?

Comment: Put some console.log() statements in your code to make sure the `selectedDateIndex` is getting set, etc. This is hard for me to troubleshoot since I cant see or test the code. However, i'll bet it's a small thing, just have to find it

Comment: I have added the code in the Plunker. Here is the link. 

https://plnkr.co/edit/SpamLtZDREW3H4tv?preview

Comment: I saw that. I played with it and couldn’t figure out why the app itself was not starting up. I can take a look at it later today or tomorrow

Comment: I made few changes to reflect what is there is my local. Now that app is starting up, you can see the drop-down is getting populated in the first div tag and the second div tag has your changes. NOW I THINK YOU CAN PLAY WITH THAT. 

https://plnkr.co/edit/SpamLtZDREW3H4tv

Comment: Ok! Here we go: https://plnkr.co/edit/JjKk3JkWvBIgDrTL  -- there was a couple typos, and a littel html cleanup. I will document and reformat my answer, but first, take a look and see if it works for you and if you have any questions. Progress at last! :)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I just checked it working fine for the date 7/30/2023 however I noticed one small issue. For the date 6/30/2022 which is the first selection in the dropdown, I am not seeing anything. It should also display the data associated with it.

Comment: Ok, we're good to go, check again: https://plnkr.co/edit/JjKk3JkWvBIgDrTL -- the issue was we were checking for `ng-if="selectedDateIndex"` and when it `==0` (the first item), that returns false. I updated it to check for `ng-if="selectedDateIndex !== null"` and now it working

Comment: I had to do ng-if="selectedDateIndex != null" which is working for both dropdown list to be displayed. However, I have one last question how should I get rid of the blank dropdown and default to the first date in the array. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: You’re welcome - please accept as the answer and upvote if you feel inclined.

Comment: I have accepted that as an answer thanks for helping me out. One last question is how should I default dataArray[0].date as a default date so that I will not be showing an empty dropdown. I think I am partially done by removing options however page load I am still getting that.

Comment: OK, you can see the changes at https://plnkr.co/edit/JjKk3JkWvBIgDrTL -- ng-options is funny. To set the default value, the ng-model has to be bound to the same object. So I put dataArray in an object., along with the default selected value, and had to call the function to show the offices. Take a look. I had to make changes to the index and script files. Also, thanks for the upvote, can you please also accept by checking the checkmark

Comment: With that change drop down is not working. I see the date is undefined for the date parameter in the function onSelectDate.

Comment: Ah, yes. That's fixed now. So, now I'm calling the `onSelectDate()` with no argument - we're using ng-model to track the selected date, so if no date is passed to that function, we just get it through `let date = $scope.ds.date;`.

Comment: Also, I updated my answer with all the new code plus explanations of the ng-options stuff.